# Not executing two events of an object

Tags: vb.net, class, events

Happy Day to all
I would need to resolve an issue of not executing two events of an object. 
I reconstructed the following class:

```
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Imports System.Data.OleDb

 Public Class FunDeletedLocalData

       Public Event ProgressDeleted(ByVal value As Integer)
       Public Event MaxProgressDeleted(value As Integer)

      Shared DataStartAppList As List(Of DataStartAppCS)
      Shared DataEndAppList As List(Of DataEndAppCS)


      Public Sub DeleteAllDataApp()
          Dim i As Integer = 0
          '**** Preparo lista Record StartApp
          'DataStartAppList = New List(Of DataStartAppCS)

          ReadDataStartAppFromDBLocaleForDelete()

          RaiseEvent MaxProgressDeleted(DataStartAppList.Count)


          For Each item As DataStartAppCS In DataStartAppList
              Try
                DataStartAppDB.DeleteDataStart(item.IdStartApp)
              Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("error transfer data to Server: " & ex.ToString, "Errore", 
                                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    Exit Sub
              End Try
              i += 1
              RaiseEvent ProgressDeleted(i)
           Next

          '**** Preparo lista Record EndApp

          DataEndAppList = New List(Of DataEndAppCS)

          ReadDataEndAppFromDBLocaleForDelete()

          RaiseEvent MaxProgressDeleted(i + DataEndAppList.Count)

          For Each item As DataEndAppCS In DataEndAppList
            Try
                 DataEndAppDB.DeleteDataEnd(item.IdEndApp)
            Catch ex As Exception
               MessageBox.Show("error transfer data to Server: " & ex.ToString, "Errore", 
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
               Exit Sub
            End Try
            i += 1
            RaiseEvent ProgressDeleted(i)
         Next
   End Sub

   Public Sub DeleteOnlyDataStartApp()
      DataStartAppList = New List(Of DataStartAppCS)

      ReadDataStartAppFromDBLocaleForDelete()

      RaiseEvent MaxProgressDeleted(DataStartAppList.Count)

      Dim i As Integer = 0
      For Each item As DataStartAppCS In DataStartAppList
        Try
           DataStartAppDB.DeleteDataStart(item.IdStartApp)
        Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show("error transfer data to Server: " & ex.ToString, "Errore", 
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
           Exit Sub
        End Try
        i += 1
        RaiseEvent ProgressDeleted(i)
      Next
  End Sub

 Sub DeleteOnlyDataEndApp()
    DataEndAppList = New List(Of DataEndAppCS)

    ReadDataEndAppFromDBLocaleForDelete()

    RaiseEvent MaxProgressDeleted(DataEndAppList.Count)

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each item As DataEndAppCS In DataEndAppList
     Try
        DataEndAppDB.DeleteDataEnd(item.IdEndApp)
     Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error transfer data to Server: " & ex.ToString, "Errore", 
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
     End Try
     i += 1
     RaiseEvent ProgressDeleted(i)
   Next
End Sub

#Region "ReadDataFromDBLocaleForDelete"

 Public Shared Function ReadDataStartAppFromDBLocaleForDelete() As Boolean
    Dim stReturn As Boolean = True
    Try
       DataStartAppList = DataStartAppDB.GetDataStartListForDelete
    Catch ex As SqlException
       stReturn = False
       Throw ex
    End Try
    Return stReturn
 End Function

 Public Shared Function ReadDataEndAppFromDBLocaleForDelete() As Boolean
    Dim stReturn As Boolean = True
    Try
       DataEndAppList = DataEndAppDB.GetDataEndListForDelete
    Catch ex As SqlException
      stReturn = False
      Throw ex
   End Try
   Return stReturn
 End Function
#End Region

 Sub New()
 End Sub
End Class
```

that deletes the records in the reference db that I pass in a list because they meet certain conditions.
On the form where the corresponding FD object is instantiated and docked its events, these main routines include:

```
Private WithEvents FD As FunDeletedLocalData

Private Sub btnAccept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAccept.Click
  btnClose.Enabled = False
  btnAccept.Enabled = False
  Me.lblRecDeleted.Visible = True
  Me.prgBar.Visible = True
  Me.Refresh()
  Dim FD = New FunDeletedLocalData
  If rdTDAll.Checked Then
     FD.DeleteAllDataApp()
  ElseIf rdStartApp.Checked Then
     FD.DeleteOnlyDataStartApp()
  ElseIf rdEndApp.Checked Then
     FD.DeleteOnlyDataEndApp()
  End If
  FD = Nothing
  btnAccept.Enabled = True
  btnClose.Enabled = True
  Me.prgBar.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub FD_ProgressDeleted(value As Integer) Handles FD.ProgressDeleted

  Me.prgBar.Maximum = value

End Sub

Private Sub FD_MaxProgressDeleted(value As Integer) Handles FD.MaxProgressDeleted

  Me.lblRecDeleted.Text = "Record Cancellati: " & value.ToString
  Me.prgBar.PerformStep()
  Me.Refresh()

End Sub
```

The whole thing works properly and the records are actually deleted and I have no error.
The only thing that doesn't work are the object events:

```
RaiseEvent MaxProgressDeleted(DataEndAppList.Count)
RaiseEvent ProgressDeleted(i)
```

They're not being thrown.
How come? In a very similar class I would say identical in that exactly equals the only differences is the call:

```
DataEndAppDB.DeleteDataEnd(item.IdEndApp)
```

as it only needs the iD to delete the record, 
whereas in the other class they're of the type:

```
DataEndAppSQLDB.AddEndApp(item)
```

Could you tell me where the problem is??
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

What's up with this:

```vb
Dim FD = New FunDeletedLocalData
```

Why are you declaring a local variable in `btnAccept_Click` instead of using the field you declared `WithEvents`? Every reference to `FD` in that method is referring to the local variable, not the field. As far as I can tell, you never assign anything to the field so what events would you be handling?

Comment: No variable is declared at class form level:Public Class frmTrasferimentoDatiToSQL
   Dim WithEvents FD As funTransfertAndDeletedData. Into the btnAccept event is instantiated

Comment: No variable is declared at class form level:Public Class frmTrasferimentoDatiToSQL
   Dim WithEvents FD As funTransfertAndDeletedData. Into the btnAccept event is instantiated.I manage event routines : Private Sub FD_MaxProgressDeleted(value As Integer) Handles FD.MaxProgressDeleted and Private Sub FD_MaxProgressDeleted(value As Integer) Handles FD.MaxProgressDeleted. Maybe you didn't get a good look at the structure of the code?

Comment: Maybe YOU didn't get a good look at the code. What exactly do you think `Private WithEvents FD As FunDeletedLocalData` is? It's a variable declared at the class level. If you don't know how variables work then you probably need to stop what you're doing and go back to learn the basics first.

Comment: @  jmcilhinney, I'm sorry, but 'FunDeletedLocalData'  is a class that provides me with routines:  DeleteAllDataApp()   DeleteOnlyDataStartApp() and DeleteOnlyDataEndApp() In the form code, I define the local variable: Private WithEvents FD As FunDeletedLocalData  that refers to the class!When some data is entered into the form and you click on the bottom Accept in the relevant event i take the FD object (otherwise it's still Nothing) and invoke the object's functions. When routines have finished they launch a RaiseEvent that should be intercepted on the form via event routines.

Comment: *"I define the local variable: Private WithEvents FD As FunDeletedLocalData"*. OK, you do need to stop and go back and learn the basics. Only members can have an access modifier so anything declared `Private` can't possibly be a local variable. A local variable is, by definition, declared inside a method. A member variable is, by definition, declared outside all methods.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney Thank you
But it is declared at the level of the Form2 class... It is used only in the Form2 class... so it should have a scope at the form2 class level... otherwise how should I declare it Share??
Thank you

Comment: You have missed the point completely. You SHOULD declare it at the class level. But the problem is that you're not using that variable that you declared at the class level. You're declaring another variable of the same type inside a method and assigning your object to that, so your field is ALWAYS `Nothing`. Keep the field and use it. Get rid of the local variable.

Comment: I'm sorry you're right. I did something stupid, and we can't see it. Thank you for your patience and for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `FD` in you `Form` is declared at the form level with

```
Private WithEvents FD As FunDeletedLocalData
```

Another variable at the method level is declared and instantiated with

```
Dim FD = New FunDeletedLocalData
```

except this time it is not declared `WithEvents`.

Below is a Minimal Complete Reproduce-able with the emphasis on minimal rework of your code. Just remove the `Dim` on the second variable in the method.

```
Public Class Form2
    Private WithEvents FD As FunDeletedLocalData
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FD = New FunDeletedLocalData
        FD.DeleteAllDataApp()
        FD.DeleteOnlyDataStartApp()
        FD.DeleteOnlyDataEndApp()
        FD = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub FD_ProgressDeleted(value As Integer) Handles FD.ProgressDeleted
        MessageBox.Show("Progress Event fired")
    End Sub

    Private Sub FD_MaxProgressDeleted(value As Integer) Handles FD.MaxProgressDeleted
        MessageBox.Show("Max Progress Event fired")
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class FunDeletedLocalData

    Public Event ProgressDeleted(ByVal value As Integer)
    Public Event MaxProgressDeleted(value As Integer)

    Public Sub DeleteAllDataApp()
        RaiseEvent ProgressDeleted(5)
        RaiseEvent MaxProgressDeleted(6)
    End Sub

    Public Sub DeleteOnlyDataStartApp()
        RaiseEvent MaxProgressDeleted(7)
        RaiseEvent ProgressDeleted(8)
    End Sub

    Sub DeleteOnlyDataEndApp()
        RaiseEvent MaxProgressDeleted(9)
        RaiseEvent ProgressDeleted(10)
    End Sub

End Class
```